# How to rotate line chart series

Tags: javafx, plot, linechart

I've the opportunity to plot several series in a line chart. Now I want to rotate one of them. Is there any way I can do this?

### Normal:

```
Y axes

|

|

----X axes
```

### What I want to get:

```
X axes

|

|

Y axes ----
```

Comment: Since a function defines one x for one y, you can simply swap these values?

Comment: No, this is a special case, I want to do this for a surjective function, for example, for a y = sin(x)

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify that. Adding a [mre] which shows how the solution proposed by @maio doesn't work, possibly accompanied by some screenshots of the problem, would also improve your question. The more specific and detailed your question is, the more likely you are to get a satisfactory answer (though it's no guarantee).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I was helped by rotation transformation of the original tabulated function and sorting values by y, as well as changing the sorting policy for line chart:

```
lineChart.setAxisSortingPolicy(LineChart.SortingPolicy.NONE);
```

As I wanted, I got
[one function along the x axis and another along the y axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXRfm.png)